# Can blade flourish be used with ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, bard, ranged-attack

In Xanathar's Guide to Everything under the Bard College of Swords Blade Flourish feature (page 15) it says *"Whenever you make an attack action...".* Was this meant for strictly melee attacks or **can Blade Flourish be used with ranged attacks?**

Answer (score 24):

Yes! Blade Flourish can be used with Ranged Attacks.

The text is very specific that it only requires a weapon attack (not a melee weapon attack or even an attack with a sword).

Additionally, Jeremy Crawford specifically states:

> Blade Flourish intentionally requires a weapon attack—not necessarily an attack using a sword.

Source: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/02/17/college-of-swords-blade-flourish-intentionally-requires-a-weapon-attack/

While you can use the sword flourish with ranged attacks, other features in the class (like Fighting Style) do not work with ranged attacks.

Answer (score 14):

### The name of an ability does not limit what the ability does

The text is:

> Whenever you take the Attack action on your turn, your walking speed increases by 10 feet until the end of the turn, and if **a weapon attack** that you make as part of this action hits a creature, you can ...

A “weapon attack” can be a melee or ranged attack with a melee, ranged or improvised weapon.